# Point link to a file on a different server - File blocked? Why?

Tags: javascript, http, web, server, ftp

I have a website, built in React, which, on one page, links to a file. That file lies on a different server (which is also owned by me). When the user clicks on that link to download it, the file is *blocked* and not downloaded. However, when the user does a right-click and opens the file in a new tab, the file is displayed in that tab - so that does work.

However, I want to enable the user to *download* it.
How can I enable the user to download the file directly from the second server by clicking on the link on the website which sits on the first server? And why would it block it anyways?

Comment: have you tried adding `target="_blank"` to the link? That'll open it in a new tab automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks. My goal is not to open it in a new tab though, but to enable the user to download it directly. I only mentioned this to ensure that the file is in fact there, and also because I find it odd that I can open it in the tab, but not download it directly.

Comment: Sure, Are you using the HTML5 download tag? It might be CORS stopping it, in which case, are the websites hosted on the same webspace? If so you could make a htaccess rule to direct `example1.com/download` to `/home/USER/public_html/example2.com/download` as an example

Comment: Yes I am using the HTML5 download tag; No they lie on completely different servers / providers. I am not sure I can follow what you are saying in the last sentence though.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console when you try clicking the link?